# Delay in connecting to SQL Server named instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking

I'm having an interesting problem.  I've just installed SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition alongside an existing installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition.  The original 2008 R2 edition is the default instance, and the new installation is a named instance called \DEV.

So far, so good.  To enable remote connections, I had to enable named pipes and TCP/IP for the new instance, plus change the login account for SQL Browser to Local System.  I also explicitly opened UDP 1434 on the local firewall.

So, new connections will now take 20sec + to establish a connection to the new instance, but will connect to the old instance (2008 R2) almost immediately.  In SQLCMD, I have to override the connection timeout with -l30.  In SSMS, the initial connection fails out but subsequent reconnections happen immediately.  Connecting with other clients, such as RedGate Backup Pro, shows the same issue - I need to amend the connection timeout to 30 seconds as a minimum.  Halving the network packet size from 4096 to 2048 helps too.

I've checked SQL Browser, file details show version is 11.x.x.x.  Checked with network team, should be no impediment to TCP/UDP traffic with external firewalls etc (besides, connection from a client in the same subnet has same issue).

Does anyone have any ideas, please?  It's infuriating.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you connect to the new instance specifying the port number, i.e. servername,2323 does it connect instantly or does it still take a while?  That should help determine if it is the client finding out the port number from the browser service causing the slowness or the instance itself.

Comment: Amendment to above, checked connectivity from a server sharing the same IP range, no architecture between them, and connection nearly instant.  In response to steoleary - I have connected via the dynamic port from that neighbouring server, instant connection, but from anywhere else I can't connect.  Suspect this is because the firewall isn't allowing traffic to the dynamic port.

I also now suspect that because this problem only manifests when there's a firewall in the way, the UDP port filtering on the firewall is somehow to blame..?

Comment: UPDATE:  Connection working fine now, but required specific addition of a local firewall rule for the dynamic TCP port being used.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2685663: PLease post that as an answer and accept it, so that the question gets closed. You are wasting everybodys time with leaving a solved question open.

Comment: Although this post is resolved i come here every time because it shows "UNANSWERED". It's really a waste of time of every body with leaving a solved question open. May be moderators can help closing down this question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you go after a named instance of SQL you are actually connecting to the SQL Discovery Service on that box and looking up the named instance information ie IP address and port #.  If you supplied ServerName, Port# in SSMS or the connection string the connection would be almost instantanous because you're skipping the step of looking up the instance.

Comment: No, it does not take 20 seconds to look up the instance.